# Convert string date into date format in python?

Tags: python, date, datetime

How to convert the below string date into date format in python.

```
input:
date='15-MARCH-2015'

expected output:
2015-03-15
```

I tried to use `datetime.strftime` and `datetime.strptime`. it is not accepting this format.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Converting string into datetime](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/466345/converting-string-into-datetime)

Answer (score 9):

You can use `datetime.strptime` with a proper format :

```
>>> datetime.strptime('15-MARCH-2015','%d-%B-%Y')
datetime.datetime(2015, 3, 15, 0, 0)
```

Read more about `datetime.strptime` and date formatting: https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior

Answer (score 2):

The `datetime` module will help you here. First convert your string to a `datetime` object using `strptime`, then convert this object to the required string format with `strftime`:

```
from datetime import datetime
datetime.strftime(datetime.strptime('15-MARCH-2015','%d-%B-%Y'),'%Y-%m-%d')
```

Will yield:

```
'2015-03-15'
```

Notice the string format `'%d-%B-%Y'` conforms to the string as you have it and  `'%Y-%m-%d'` to the format you want it to be in.

Answer (score -2):

You can use [easy_date](https://github.com/ralphavalon/easy_date) to make it easy:

```
import date_converter
converted_date = date_converter.string_to_string('15-MARCH-2015', '%d-%B-%Y', '%Y-%m-%d')
```